# Displaying a Long Message with Strings and a Full Array in a Dialog Box

Tags: java

So I'm working on a little e-store program right now that does a bunch of basic e-store functions. I have to have a button that comes up with a sort of 'View Order' dialog box that displays date/time, list of things purchased, subtotal, etc.

So here's my problem. If I do a dialog box set up like this:

```js
    private void viewActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list);
    }
```

Where 'list' is my array with all of the items ordered, this will print out, which is what I want:

[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfBVt.png)

But if I add more things to the JOptionPane code, like this:

```js
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Date: " + x.format(dNow) + "\n\n"  
                + "Number of line items: " + count + "\n\n" 
                + "Item# / ID / Title / Price / Qty / Disc % / Subtotal\n\n"
                + list);
```

With list at the end of the dialogue box, I get this:

[wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrveY.png)

With the highlighted part being the array 'list'. I want that highlighted portion to display just like it does in my other dialogue box with just the array. The 'list' array in the second code snippet is underlined (Netbeans) and says "Array concatenated with String". Any help? I'd post my whole code but it's super messy right now.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

- Create a JTable,
- create an appropriate TableModel for it, one with the appropriate columns (i.e., Item#, ID, Title, Price, Qty, Disc %, Subtotal),
- add your data to the model,
- set the model to the JTable,
- add the table to a JScrollPane and
- then display that in your JOptionPane.

---

Quick and dirty option 2:

- Use a non-editable, non-focusable JTextArea,
- Give it a `Font.MONOSPACED` type Font
- Create your data table by appending to the JTextArea true *formatted* text -- not tabs but rather use of `String.Format(...)`